On Ubuntu, I know that a VM will permanently take up a bit of RAM for kernel modules, but I'm curious to know how much exactly. thanks
And would this amount be the same for Windows if I ran a VM there?

You've tagged your question about the very much EOL release of Ubuntu 14.04? (2014-April release); is that correct?    (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/)   Kernel modules are specific to a kernel; and given a Ubuntu LTS release has kernel stack choice (GA, HWE, OEM etc) the kernel modules used by each may vary on just the same release too don't forget

At least some VMs can be set to either use RAM dynamically or statically (fixed amount of RAM). If statically, it will use the same amount of RAM independent of the operating system in the VM. If dynamically, it will use RAM depending of the operating system and the application programs used. If you want to minimize the use of RAM, please try the light-weight flavours of Ubuntu, for example Lubuntu and Xubuntu. You can also try other (non-Ubuntu) light-weight linux distros, for example Puppy Linux or Tiny Core.
